# can anyone test this json and tell me if they experience the same problem am having

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/contact-card-format
create 1 list and populate it with 40 rows then scroll down to the 30th item , you will see blank space under the 30th row item, wont show beyond the 30th, when i inspect the page the list loads the rest of the rows in the page

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I ran into the same issue as you, and there will be a blank when scrolling down the view.

It seems to take time to load items.

Comment: is there a fix for this issue?